# On click method on thumbnail-card in bixby

Tags: bixby, bixbystudio

I am showing multiple choices on user's screen with thumbnail-card in bixby. Have added the slots  for click as well. What I am trying to achieve is if user click on the thumbnail, i should get the id of the particular card and process it for further information.This is the layout

```
layout-macro-def (artist-thumbnail-card) {
params {
param (artistchoice) {
  type (ArtistChoiceResult)
  min (Required) max (One)
}
}
content {
thumbnail-card {
  image-position (Start)

  image-url ("#{value(artistchoice.multiple_image)}")
  title-area {
    halign (Start)
    slot1 {
      text {
        value ("#{value(artistchoice.multiple_name)}")
        style (Title_S)
      }
    }
    slot2 {
      single-line {
        text {
          value ("From #{value(artistchoice.multiple_cat)}")
          style (Detail_L_Soft)
        }
      }
    }
  }
  on-click {
    intent {
      goal: ArtistSearch
    }
  }
}
}
}
```

And this is the result view

```
result-view {
  match: ArtistChoiceResult (artistchoice) {
    from-output: ArtistChoice
  }

  message {
    template ("Please select one of the following")
  }

  render {
    if (size(artistchoice) > 1) {
     list-of (artistchoice) {
       has-details (true)
       where-each (item) {
         layout-macro (artist-thumbnail-card) {
         param (artistchoice) {
           expression (item)
        }
      }
    }
  }
} else-if (size(artistchoice) == 1) {
  layout-match (artistchoice) {
    mode (Details)
  }
}
}
}
```

I am not able to send the ID information to the artistSearch Intent. How will I achieve that. And I have Id in other variable, so how do i pass that value?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the code you have provided, we have to assume 2 things:
1) This is the result-view that is triggered for an `artistchoice` structure
2) The `multiple_name` is an array that holds all the options.

Given the above assumptions, you would need to build a layout where each of the elements of `multiple_name` (`multiple_name[1]`, `multiple_name[2]`, `multiple_name[3]`, etc.).

Since one on-click event cannot be defined with variable click events, you would need to create a separate card for each multiple choice option so there is one on-click event per card. This would allow the on-click to look like the following:

```
on-click {
    intent {
      goal: ArtistSearch
      value-set: [YOUR CONCEPT HERE]{$expr(artistchoice.multiple_name[1])}
    }
  }
```

If you need any further information, please reach out to the [support team](https://support.bixbydevelopers.com/hc/en-us/requests/new) where we can discuss any particular issues you're facing that may be unique to your use case.

Comment: Have updated the question. I am able to see the thumbnail one by one but when click on the thumbnail, I want information of that thumbnail, perticulerly id of artist,which is stored in multiple_id, should go to ArtistSearch, where it is been handled and proceed further.

Comment: You would need to have the `multiple_id` that you want to use contained within the `artistchoice` Structure if you want it available for the `on-click` event in this layout macro.